# When JTable row is selected button should be visible in that row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

Actually I am having problem while working with `JTable`.

I have three columns in my table.

The table structure is like :

```
Parameter Name | Parameter Type | Operation
```

Above are the three columns in it ..
Consider table contains one row as like:

```
Parameter Name | Parameter Type | Operation
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Request            |         String          |     [Delete]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response          |         String          |     [Delete]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here [Delete] is the button.
This is all the scenario..

Now what I want is that whenever I select the row then only delete button should be visible.

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Custom DefaultTableRenderer and a Custom TableCellEditor

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
public class ButtonTable extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ButtonTable dialog = new ButtonTable();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public ButtonTable() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPanel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPanel.columnWidths = new int[]{414, 0};
        gbl_contentPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{240, 0};
        gbl_contentPanel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPanel.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPanel.setLayout(gbl_contentPanel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

        table = new JTable() { 
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return column == 2;
            };
        };
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"ONE", null, null},
                {"TWO", null, null},
                {"THREE", null, null},
                {"FOUR", null, null},
                {"FIVE", null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "First Column", "Second Column", "Button"
            }
        ));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(196);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(180);
        table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new TableEditor(new JTextField()));
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableRenderer());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}

class TableEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    //This is just because the Constructor of superclass needs a JTextField, or JCheckBox or whatever...
    public TableEditor(JTextField field) {
        super(field);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

        if (isSelected && column == 2)
            return new JButton("Delete");
        return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }
}

class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (isSelected && column == 2)
            return new JButton("Delete");
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                row, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);` -1  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.  The only excuse for showing `null` layouts on SO, is when the answer is trying to stick as close as possible to the code provided by the person asking.  Even then, it is not a very ***good*** excuse.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Erm... that's not for him to use that part of the code. I was demonstrating how to use the renderer and the editor and not giving that as the main program. Btw, I use GridBagLayout as my Layout Manager.
Don't see the reason to give -1 for that. But it's up to you.

Comment: I won't down-vote the answer, but agree with Andrew in that we should not encourage newbies to use null layout, and that showing it in sample code does just that. I will reserve my up-vote for one that doesn't use null layout.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I appreciate that you don't down-vote my answer. And I agree with both of you. Next time I'll just show the part of code that really matter and, if I have to show the full case, I'll use the GridbagLayout :D. As I did yesterday in another question.

Comment: Edited to add the GBL to the code